# C# Not getting all cookies from website

Tags: c#, cookies

i'm creating a application that gets all cookies from a certain website. For some reason I can't manage to get all the cookies from the website, is this problem fixable?

```
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        try
        {
            string url = textBox1.Text;

            HttpWebRequest myCall = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 
            myCall.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            response = (HttpWebResponse)myCall.GetResponse();
            myCall.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

            foreach (Cookie cookie in response.Cookies)
            {

                listBox1.Items.Add(cookie.Name);
                listBox1.Items.Add(cookie.Value);
            }
            myCall.Abort();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: please show the HTTP response and what values you are getting back.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are trying to get cookies from sites across domains? Cookies can only be shared across sites within the same domain.